# Firebase push notification is not received on the iOS device. Although console logs the message, it is received on device

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have created a sample ios application as per the instructions provided in the Firebase console to receive cloud messages on ios devices. Notification message is sent from the console and gets printed on the app console as well. But the push notification is not received on the device even after giving necessary permission.

I'm using swift 3 and xCode version 10.3. Registered the app in Firebase console and required FCM token is received through the app and added to send a test message to the device. Tried sending lot of messages through the console but none of them are shown on the device. It shows as the messages are being sent successfully on the console.

Following is my AppDelegate.swift file that I have written to receive the push notification.

```
import UIKit
import UserNotifications
import Firebase
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseInstanceID

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?
    let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {

            FirebaseApp.configure()           

            Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
            Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

            let authOptions: UNAuthorizationOptions = [.alert, .badge, .sound]
            UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(
                options: authOptions,
                completionHandler: {_, _ in })
        } else {
            let settings: UIUserNotificationSettings =
                UIUserNotificationSettings(types: [.alert, .badge, .sound], categories: nil)
            application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings)
        }


        // request permission from user to send notification
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound], completionHandler: { authorized, error in
            if authorized {
                DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                    application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                })
            }
            else{
                print("Notification access denied")
            }
        })
        return true
    }


    // [START receive_message]
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }

        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
        print("Unable to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
        Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
        print("APNs token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")


    }

}

@available(iOS 10, *)
extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    // Receive displayed notifications for iOS 10 devices.
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        print(userInfo)
         print("Message ID: \(userInfo["gcm.message_id"]!)")
        completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptions.alert)

    }

    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

        print("Do what ever you want")
        // Print full message.
        print("tap on on forground app",userInfo)


        completionHandler()
    }
}

extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String) {
        print("Firebase registration token: \(fcmToken)")
        Messaging.messaging().subscribe(toTopic: "/topics/nutriewell_live")
        Messaging.messaging().shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true

    }

    func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceive remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("Received data message: \(remoteMessage.appData)")
    }


}
```

I expected a push notification on the ios device but I'm not receiving any.
I'm getting the following output which gets printed with the notification message sent from the console.

```
2019-08-15 11:20:32.548066+0530 FirebaseIos[800:207059]  - <AppMeasurement>[I-ACS036002] Analytics screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. 




To disable screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseScreenReportingEnabled to NO (boolean) in the Info.plist



2019-08-15 11:20:32.949393+0530 FirebaseIos[800:207068] 6.2.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM001000] FIRMessaging Remote Notifications proxy enabled, will swizzle remote notification receiver handlers. If you'd prefer to manually integrate Firebase Messaging, add "FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled" to your Info.plist, and set it to NO. 


Firebase registration token: fsyB51mCvbg:APA91bFvRFPIxauHfKA-v-K29YTWl_TYFTgCpnvODrFA2rG8qN-F8vcLIWcZ-lOChkJw-pIBVhcxg2epBz7AYVALMNLC4Hs6M4ds_pQXytYymjr15KMqOt08_7PkmYkU1jHy6xcw5hvx
2019-08-15 11:20:34.914040+0530 FirebaseIos[800:207059] 6.2.0 - [Firebase/Messaging][I-FCM002024] Format '/topics/nutriewell_live' is deprecated. Only 'nutriewell_live' should be used in subscribeToTopic.
Notification access denied


2019-08-15 11:20:48.869741+0530 FirebaseIos[800:207068] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C7.1:2][0x101537e10] get output frames failed, state 8196




Received data message: [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "firebase ios";
    e = 1;
    tag = "campaign_collapse_key_3627158360856700759";
    title = "firebase!";
}, AnyHashable("from"): 591363996390, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.combank.Firebase.Ios]
%@ [AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "firebase ios";
    e = 1;
    tag = "campaign_collapse_key_3627158360856700759";
    title = "firebase!";
}, AnyHashable("from"): 591363996390, AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.combank.Firebase.Ios]





    Received data message: [AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.combank.Firebase.Ios, AnyHashable("from"): 591363996390, AnyHashable("notification"): {
        body = "firebase ios";
        e = 1;
        tag = "campaign_collapse_key_750970355066402639";
        title = "firebase!";
    }]




%@ [AnyHashable("collapse_key"): com.combank.Firebase.Ios, AnyHashable("from"): 591363996390, AnyHashable("notification"): {
    body = "firebase ios";
    e = 1;
    tag = "campaign_collapse_key_750970355066402639";
    title = "firebase!";
}]




2019-08-15 11:22:34.475335+0530 FirebaseIos[800:207131] [BoringSSL] nw_protocol_boringssl_get_output_frames(1301) [C1.1:2][0x1015273f0] get output frames failed, state 8196
```

Any help I can get here for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to receive notification:

1. when the app is closed/inactive and you get the payload in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:
2. when the application is open/active and currently visible you get payload in didReceiveRemoteNotification:

When your application is closed, iOS take care of displaying a notification (if notification extension not developed) and launch your app when you tap on it.

If your application is open you have to take care of displaying this notification or ignore it.

Here what official documentation says:

> When local and remote notifications are not handled directly by your
>   app or the user, they are displayed in **Notification Center** so that
>   they can be viewed later. Use the
>   **getDeliveredNotificationsWithCompletionHandler:** method of the shared **UNUserNotificationCenter** object to get a list of
>   notifications still being displayed in Notification Center. If you
>   find any notifications that are now outdated and should not be
>   displayed to the user, you can remove them using the
>   **removeDeliveredNotificationsWithIdentifiers:** method.

[official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/SupportingNotificationsinYourApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH4-SW1)